# How can I display the IndexRoute and NewRoute at once in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have an "orders" resource defined with two routes, one being the default index route and the other being a "new" route.

I can then display the list of orders in the OrdersIndexRoute, but I want to display the OrdersNewRoute as a popup window over the top of the list. When I transition to the OrdersNewRoute then the OrdersIndexRoute is replaced and the list therefore disappears.

Is there anyway to display the two routes at the same time in different outlets?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though it is easier than I thought. I just add the rendering to the renderTemplate method of my OrdersNewRoute.

```
renderTemplate: function () {
    this.render('orders/index');
    this.render('orders/new', {
        outlet: 'new'
    });
}
```